# "Center" table offset, to account for floating figure?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, floats, wrapfigure

I'm composing a document in which I use the `wrapfig` environment to let me wrap text around a floating figure. I've placed this figure (of width `0.3\textwidth`) on the right of a page, and I'd like to include a table inline with the text that's wrapping around the figure, centered relative to the `0.7\textwidth` I have left. Unfortunately:

- When using a regular `center` environment (and no `table`, just `tabular`), the table's centered with respect to the entire page
- When using the `table` environment, the table floats with regard to the text - I'd like it to stay exactly where I put it, rather than head to the bottom or top of the page like a figure (and I can't really figure out how to center it anyway)
- When using `wraptable`, I get warnings about wrapped figure collisions, and the table continues to float relative to the text

Is there a way I can tell LaTeX to "center" a `tabular` environment only in the left `0.7\textwidth` of a page?

**Edit:** To be clearer, here's a snippet of my current file:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.3\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=0.28\textwidth]{someimage.png}
\end{wrapfigure}

Some text here...

\begin{tabular}{c}
table info...
\end{tabular}

More text here...
```

I'd very much like the layout to look like:

```
Some text here...                                 someimage.png
                                                  someimage.png
                table info...                     someimage.png
                                                  someimage.png
More text here...                                 someimage.png
```

Note how the table info is centered but only in the left portion of the page. I'm looking for the environment I can use to make that happen with the `tabular` chunk I have now.

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you're trying to achieve. First, is your figure a "float" in the (normal) LaTeX sense of the word? If it has be located in the cutout generated by `wrapfig`, how can it be a "float"? Second, it appears that you want the tabular stuff to be located to the `right` of the figure, with text above and below (but not to either side, right?) it. If so, why not place the `table` and `figure` environments in side-by-side minipages of width `0.7\textwidth` and `0.3\textwidth`, respectively -- and *not* "wrap" them inside a paragraph...

Comment: @Mico: Sorry I was unclear! I've edited the question to (hopefully) show better what I mean.

Comment: So am I correct to assume that you want the table and to figure together to take up the whole width of the page? In that case, what you need is two minipage environments, side by side. Make their combined width equal to the overall textwidth.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do this using `\parshape`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
\begin{document}

% Setup picture inclusion
\newsavebox{\myimage}%
\savebox{\myimage}{\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{image}}%
\newlength{\mylinewidth}\setlength{\mylinewidth}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\wd\myimage-1em}% Leave a horizontal 1em gap

\null\hfill\smash{\raisebox{-\height}{\usebox{\myimage}}} \par \vspace*{-\dimexpr.7\baselineskip+\parskip}% Insert image
\parshape=1 0pt \mylinewidth
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras ultrices, 
nunc aliquam ultrices euismod, lorem velit hendrerit urna, vel imperdiet 
mi magna sed mauris.

\parshape=1 0pt \mylinewidth
\begin{center}
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    \hline
    \textbf{Heading 1} & \textbf{Heading 2} & \textbf{Heading 3} \\
    One & Two & Three \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\parshape=3
0pt \mylinewidth 0pt \mylinewidth 0pt \linewidth
Donec et bibendum nulla. Donec laoreet mauris a turpis iaculis malesuada. 
Integer semper cursus erat, ut blandit felis posuere a. Sed neque nisl, 
porttitor eu viverra in, scelerisque vel nisi. Aliquam consectetur aliquam 
facilisis. Proin magna velit, euismod eget pretium eu, euismod ut velit. 
Praesent adipiscing imperdiet arcu eget congue. Integer et tellus ut quam 
blandit malesuada.

\end{document}
```

The image is first set, followed by a paragraph that leaves a `1em` horizontal space between the text and the image via `\parshape=1 0pt \mylinewidth`. Here `\mylinewidth` is specifically set as `\linewidth-<image width>-1em`. Subsequent paragraphs are also set using this approach, while the last paragraph width is only modified for the rows affected by the image placement. In the MWE, this includes *only* the first 3 lines - the first two are set within `\mylinewidth`, while the third (and following) stretch the entire `\linewidth`.

Regarding the `\parshape` primitive, the following is taken from **Chapter 14: How TeX Breaks Paragraphs into Lines** (p 101) of the TeX Book:

> You can specify an essentially arbitrary paragraph shape by saying
>   `\parshape=<number>`, where the `<number>` is a positive integer `n`,
>   followed by `2n` `<dimen>` specifications. In general, `\parshape=n i1
>   l1 i2 l2 ... in ln` specifies a paragraph whose first `n` lines will
>   have lengths `l1`, `l2`, ..., `ln`, respectively, and they will be
>   indented from the left margin by the respective amounts `i1`, `i2`,
>   ..., `in`. If the paragraph has fewer than `n` lines, the additional
>   specifications will be ignored; if it has more than `n` lines, the
>   specifications for line `n` will be repeated ad infinitum. You can
>   cancel the effect of a previously specified `\parshape` by saying
>   `\parshape=0`.

It would be possible to modify the layout if you want the image to start a different line.